# Разделяй и властвуй: подсчет количества инверсий в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Есть функция для подсчета инверсий в массиве, требующая **О(n2)** времени:

```
    static void Inverses(int[] A, ref int count)
    { 
        count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < A.Length; j++)
            {
                if( A[i] > A[j] )
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Также есть функция сортировки массива подходом **разделяй и властвуй**, требующая **O(n*log(n))** времени:

```
    static Int32[] Merge_Sort(Int32[] massive)
    {
        if (massive.Length == 1)
            return massive;
        Int32 mid_point = massive.Length / 2;
        return Merge(Merge_Sort(massive.Take(mid_point).ToArray()), Merge_Sort(massive.Skip(mid_point).ToArray()));
    }

    static Int32[] Merge(Int32[] mass1, Int32[] mass2)
    {
        Int32 a = 0, b = 0;
        Int32[] merged = new int[mass1.Length + mass2.Length];
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < mass1.Length + mass2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (b < mass2.Length && a < mass1.Length)
                if (mass1[a] > mass2[b])
                    merged[i] = mass2[b++];
                else //if int go for
                    merged[i] = mass1[a++];
            else
                if (b < mass2.Length)
                    merged[i] = mass2[b++];
                else
                    merged[i] = mass1[a++];
        }
        return merged;
    }
```

Нужно реализовать алгоритм **подсчета инверсий в массиве** с подходом **разделяй и властвуй**, которому требовалось бы **O(n*log(n))** времени.

К сожалению, мне достаточно тяжело дается понимание рекурсии, когда первый метод вызывает другой метод, а другой вызывает первый при условии.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Yodaness problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2987605/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987605/minimum-number-of-swaps-needed-to-change-array-1-to-array-2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Вам сначала нужно разобраться с сортировкой слиянием, а именно понять идею алгоритма, а потом уже разбираться с инверсией.

Скажу кратко: мы разбиваем массив на две части, каждую из этих частей, в свою очередь, тоже разбиваем на две части и т.д., пока наши части не будут состоять из одного элемента.
После разбиения мы сливаем парами части в одну так, чтобы результирующая часть была отсортирована - *сравниваем элементы одной части с элементами другой соответственно и записываем их в нужном порядке в результирующую*. Затем полученные части мы опять попарно сольем и т.д., пока у нас не останется одна часть, которая и будет являться отсортированным массивом.

Текстом трудно понять, поэтому рекомендую посмотреть графическую демонстрацию (на той же википедии есть гифка). Когда поймете идею, уже можно вникать и в реализацию.

**Насчет инверсий**

Когда мы сливаем обе части, как я уже говорил, мы сравниваем элементы одной (первой, левой) части с элементами другой (правой, второй) части соответственно. И если элемент левой части больше элемента правой части соответственно, то значит это и есть инверсия.
И так же все оставшиеся элементы левой части тоже будут больше, т.к. левая и правая часть отсортированы. Поэтому количество инверсий нужно увеличить на количество оставшихся элементов + 1 (текущий элемент).

**UPD:**

Вот и пример.

Индексация идет с 0. Не описывал, что добавляем элементы в результирующую часть, думаю, это и так понятно. Описал только те части, в которых есть инверсии. Возможны ошибки, т.к. быстро делал. Да и пришлось так сжато уместить элементы, чтобы картинка полностью отобразилась на хэшкоде.

[image]

Comment: Можете привести пример функции?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int[] Merge_Sort(int[] arr, ref int counter)
{
    if (arr.Length == 1)
        return arr;
    int mid_point = arr.Length / 2;
    int[] a;


    Merge(Merge_Sort(arr.Take(mid_point).ToArray(), ref counter), Merge_Sort(arr.Skip(mid_point).ToArray(), ref counter), out a, ref counter);
    return a;
}

public static void Merge(int[] mass1, int[] mass2, out int[] merged, ref int counter)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;            
    merged = new int[mass1.Length + mass2.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mass1.Length + mass2.Length; i++)
    {
        if (b < mass2.Length && a < mass1.Length)
            if (mass1[a] > mass2[b])
            {
                merged[i] = mass2[b++];
                counter = counter + (mass1.Length - a);
            }
            else //if int go for 
            {
                merged[i] = mass1[a++];
            }
        else
            if (b < mass2.Length)
        {
            merged[i] = mass2[b++];
        }
        else
        {
            merged[i] = mass1[a++];
        }                
    }            
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: собственно это не является ответом на поставленный вопрос... Это сортировка слиянием а не поиск числа инверсий.

Answer (score 0):

Инверсии легко считывается при реализации сортировки слиянием. При каждом случае, где элемент правого массива меньше левого, в переменную счетчика инверсии добавляется кол-во оставшихся левого, а именно от размера левого массива отнимаем текущий номер сравниваемого этого массива (левого).

```
public class Inverse {

    private static long inverseCount;

    public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
        inverseCount = 0;
        if (array == null) return null;
        if (array.length == 0) return array;
        return sort(array,0,array.length - 1);
    }

    static int[] sort(int[] array, int low, int high) {
        if (low > high - 1) return new int[] { array[low] };
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

        return merge(sort(array,low,mid), sort(array,mid + 1, high));
    }

    static int[] merge(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int cursor1 = 0;
        int cursor2 = 0;
        int[] merged = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
        int mergedCursor = 0;

        while (cursor1 < array1.length && cursor2 < array2.length) {

            if (array1[cursor1] <= array2[cursor2]) 
                merged[mergedCursor++] = array1[cursor1++];
            else {
                merged[mergedCursor++] = array2[cursor2++];
                inverseCount += (array1.length - cursor1);
            }
        }

        while (cursor1 < array1.length)
            merged[mergedCursor++] = array1[cursor1++];

        while (cursor2 < array2.length)
            merged[mergedCursor++] = array2[cursor2++];

        return merged;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = { 54, 4, 43, 2 };
        sort(test);
        System.out.println(inverseCount);
    }
}
```