# Как посчитать сходство двух пользователей не зная объектов оценивания?

Tags: алгоритм, статистика

Предположим следующую ситуацию:

Два пользователя оценивают статьи на новостном сайте. Мы не знаем, какие именно статьи они оценили, но знаем, что все они относятся к категории "наука". Также мы знаем их оценки выставленные в этой категории. Они представлены следующим списком:

```
u1=[8,6,4,8,8,9] , u2=[7,3,8,4,3,9,9,5,8,3,5,8] .
```

Задачей является определить сходство этих двух пользователей. Результат должен быть в процентном соотношении. Т.е. от 0 до 100%.

**UPD: Задача решена, но если есть замечания или предложения - буду рад услышать.**

Comment: Что есть "похожи" сформулируйте хотя бы для себя.

Comment: среднее возьмите

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, similarity - степень похожести двух объектов. Например, если у нас два пользователя ставят оценки u1=[10, 9, 4] и u2=[10, 4, 9], то они похожи на 100%. Или же если один поставил 10, а второй 9, то похожи на 90%. Проблема в том, что количество оценок может быть разное. Похожесть также можно охарактеризовать другим примером: "есть красный мяч и розовое ведро. На сколько они похожи?". Похожесть разных объектов мы можем судить по их признакам. В данном случае это может быть форма, материал, цвет и т.д. Например, сравнивая красный и розовый похожесть будет 0,05 (образно) или 5%.

Comment: @Mirdin, думал над средним, но это кажется очень не точным значением. К примеру, если один пользователь оценил 30 объектов в среднем на 9, а второй оценил всего 1 на 9 - можно ли сказать, что они похожи? Мне кажется, что только с огромной натяжкой.

Comment: Уточняйте вопрос

Comment: @KromStern, куда ж еще уточнить то? Если логика отходит от стандартной - это не значит, что она не правильная. Стандартные алгоритмы схожести основаны на идее, что два пользователя оценивают множество одних и тех же объектов. Зная их оценки можем посчитать на сколько они похожи. У меня же другая ситуация: эти два пользователя могут оценивать совершенно разные объекты. Их объединяет только то, что все они находятся в одной категории.

Comment: @alex.krestin ок, раз вы ищете алгоритм, выдающий конкретную метрику, вы должны знать какой именно результат он должен выдать на данных из вопроса. мне кажется что 0.6234543. если какое-то другое значение - скажите какое именно и почему.

Comment: Что такое "определенная категория предметов" в вашем случае?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [алгоритма Вагнера-Фишера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC_.D0.92.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.C2.A0.E2.80.94_.D0.A4.D0.B8.D1.88.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0), надо будет только подумать над весовыми функциями.

Comment: @PashaPash, Вы правы. Результат должен быть от 0 до 1. Чтобы можно было сказать, что пользователь1 похож на пользователя2 на 6,3632% или же у них 100% сходство, к примеру.

Comment: @KromStern, к примеру, пользователи оценивают научные новости. Значит в данном случае категория будет "наука".

Comment: @alex.krestin по ваше определение попадает обычный `если массивы равны то 1 иначе 0`. для примера из вопроса результат - 0. если вас устраивает такое решение - я запощу его как ответ. если не устраивает - приведите **конкретный** пример, на котором оно вас не устраивает, и **конктретное** ожидаемое значение.

Comment: @Yaant расстояние Левенштейна учитывает порядок. тут, насколько я понял, порядок неважен.

Comment: @PashaPash, выше было ожидаемое значение: от 0 до 1. Сейчас думаю в сторону мягкой косинусной меры, но не знаю как ее изменить. Идея следующая: сводим массивы до одинаковой длины (считаем сколько раз повторяется оценка; длина каждого массива будет 10). Составляем матрицу похожести оценок (к примеру, 10:9 как 0,9; 6:4 как 0,8 и т.д.). Проблема в том как применить эту матрицу к векторам. [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] и [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0] должны дать 0,9, но по косинусной мере дает 0.

Comment: @alex.krestin вы понимаете что значит "конкретное" значение? назовите одно единственное действительное число, которое должно быть результатом сравнения массивов из вопроса. не диапазон, не "должно быть действительное число от 0 до 1" - а конкретный ожидаемый результат на конкретных входных данных. потому что пока `если массивы равны то 1 иначе 0` соответствует всем вашим ограничениям.

Comment: @PashaPash, на векторах выше должно быть 0,9. На других примерах это может быть 0,67543 или что то подобное. Не знаю как вам еще объяснить. Если бы я мог посчитать результат для более сложных данных, не было бы этого вопроса. Я пытаюсь найти правильный алгоритм сравнения, который подходил бы в этой ситуации. К примеру, косинусная мера это практически то, что нужно, но она не подходит для векторов, в которых есть нули. Если предположить, что два пользователя ставят всего по одной оценке: один - 7, второй - 9, то результат должен быть где-то 0,8. А при применении косинусной меры выходит 0.

Comment: @alex.krestin почему именно 0.9, а не, скажем 0.89 и не 0.91?

Comment: @alex.krestin а вы нормализуйте массивы. по индексу i пишите не количество оценок = i, а количество оценок > i. или < i. тогда для одной 9 и одной 10 вы будете сравнивать [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] и [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]. лучше чем ничего. ну или размажте оценку, чтобы одна 5-ка выглядела как [0,0,0,1,3,1,0,0,0,0]. и тогда вы будете сравнивать [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,1] и [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3]

Comment: @PashaPash Ну так в этом случае ничего не мешает сравнивать заранее отсортированные массивы. Ну и к тому же, алгоритм применим не только к расстоянию Левенштейна, а и к более общему понятию расстояния между строками. Достаточно взять цену перестановки символов равной нулю, и вопрос порядка отпадет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

Пускай на входе имеем эти два массива: `u1=[8,6,4,8,8,9] , u2=[7,3,8,4,3,9,9,5,8,3,5,8]` .

Нормализуем их посчитав количество одинаковых оценок. В итоге получим: `u1=[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,3,1,0] , u2=[0,0,3,1,2,0,1,3,2,0]`

Создадим матрицу схожести оценок, приняв, что 1:10 как 0 и 10:1 как 0. Т.е. сходство между 1 и 10 нулевое. Заполним недостающие данные. На основании данной матрицы построим еще одну с коэффициентами для каждой оценки.

Представим каждую оценку как сумму произведений схожести оценки на коэффициент. К примеру, оценка `7` будет "размыта" по всему массиву и примет вид `[0.3333, 0.4444, 0.5556, 0.6667, 0.7778, 0.8889, 1.0000, 0.8889, 0.7778, 0.6667]`

После применения этой fuzzy логики наши массивы будут иметь вид:

```
u1=[1.7336, 2.4659, 3.1983, 3.9307, 4.5361, 5.1415, 5.5623, 5.9831, 5.5904, 4.8580]
u2=[3.7045, 4.9319, 6.1593, 7.0816, 7.8769, 8.3646, 8.8522, 9.1176, 8.5694, 7.3421]
```

Теперь мы спокойно можем применить корреляцию Пирсона чтобы узнать схожесть этих пользователей. Коэффициент детерминации для данного примера составляет 0.9696 . Т.е. наши пользователи похожи на 96,96%.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться *задачей подсчета инверсий*

[Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375825/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5).

Если инверсий 0 значит предпочтения пользователей одинаковые, если инверсий "много" значит предпочтения разные.